# Apply a style to a specific ice:column

Tags: css, jsf-2, icefaces-2

My question is pretty basic but cannot find an answer on Google. I do wonder if I missed something about the ice:column component.

I do use code like :

```
<ice:panelGrid columns="3">
  <ice:column style="background-color: yellow;">
    <ice:outputText value="..." />
  </ice:column>
  <ice:column>
    // row content
  </ice:column>
  <ice:column>
    // row content
  </ice:column>

  // other rows
</ice:panelGrid>
```

It seems that the column component has a style and styleClass attribute, however nothing is ever rendered in the HTML.

How do you apply a style to a perticular cell of a table with IceFaces ?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like as standard JSF `<h:panelGrid>` the `<ice:panelGrid>` has a `columnClasses` attribute which allows you to specify a comma-separated list of column classes which are to be applied subsequently on the columns. Also, in standard JSF `<h:panelGrid>`, the `<h:column>` is not supported. This is only suppored in `<h:dataTable>`. Instead, every direct child of `<h:panelGrid>` is treated as a single column, which can be just `<h:outputText>` or `<h:panelGroup>` if you have multiple components which need to go in a single column.

So, this should do:

```html
<ice:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="col1,col2,col3">
    <ice:panelGroup>row 1 col 1</ice:panelGroup>
    <ice:panelGroup>row 1 col 2</ice:panelGroup>
    <ice:panelGroup>row 1 col 3</ice:panelGroup>

    <ice:panelGroup>row 2 col 1</ice:panelGroup>
    <ice:panelGroup>row 2 col 2</ice:panelGroup>
    <ice:panelGroup>row 2 col 3</ice:panelGroup>

    ...
</ice:panelGrid>
```

which will generate

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td class="col1">row 1 col 1</td>
       <td class="col2">row 1 col 2</td>
       <td class="col3">row 1 col 3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td class="col1">row 2 col 1</td>
       <td class="col2">row 2 col 2</td>
       <td class="col3">row 2 col 3</td>
     </tr>
     ...
   </tbody>
</table>
```

You can specify the style in the `.col1`, `.col2` and `.col3` classes the usual way.

```
.col1 {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Right, I understand for the <ice:column> which should not be accepted (but perfectly works...). But how do I set a styleClass to a <td> element, but only of one of the rows ? I need to highlight a special cell in one column.

Comment: Perhaps it's an IceFaces specific feature that the `<ice:column>` works that way. If you want to set the style class on a specific cell instead of a specific column, then you need to set it on the cell itself. In your example, that would be on the `<ice:outputText>`. Make it `display: block;` as well if you want the content to cover the entire cell.

Comment: Yeah, thought about this too. I don't really like to change the display of a <span> for block, that's not what the markup is made for. Or I can use an outputText without rendering the span and place manually a <div>. But I hate being limited by the language. The proper way is to set a class directly on the <td>.